# Finding the Second Central Moment of a Martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

Assuming that $X_0=a \in [0,1]$ where $X_n$ is a martingale and $$P(X_{n+1}=\frac{X_n}{2}|\textit F_n)=1-X_n,\>\>\>P(X_{n+1}=\frac{1+X_n}{2}|F_n)=X_n$$

How may we show that  $\bf{E[(X_{n+1}-X_n)^2]=\frac{1}{4}E[X_n(1-X_n)}$

My first attempt was to rearrage the probabilities of each term so that for example

$$P(X_{n+1}=\frac{X_n}{2}|\textit F_n)=\frac{E[X_{n+1}|[\frac{X_n}{2}|\textit F_n]]}{X_{n+1}}$$ and then where $\frac{1}{2}X_n|\textit{F_n}=\frac{1}{2}X_{n-1}$ so that $$P(X_{n+1}=\frac{X_n}{2}|\textit F_n)=\frac{E[X_{n+1}|\frac{1}{2}X_{n-1}]}{X_{n+1}}=1-X_n$$

But frankly I'm just getting more and more confused on how to proceed whilst being slightly overwhelmed by each tidbit of intuition that arrives with an additional variable.

Comment: Just use $$E[A|F] = \underbrace{E[A|option1, F]}_{\mbox{function of $X$}}\underbrace{P[option1|F]}_{1-X}+E[A|option2, F]P[option2|F]$$ with the understanding that knowledge of $F$ implies knowledge of $X$.

Comment: By the way I cannot understand the first equation after your sentence "rearrange the probabilities."  I think you are trying to make this problem too hard. You seem to be conditioning on $(X_n/2)|F$, I'm not sure what that even means, are you making that notation up?

Comment: @Michael Yeah conditioning on $F$ where $F$ is meant to be the entire set of outcomes or the sigma field of previous outcomes in the sequence. I hope I'm not making this up :[

Comment: You are not conditionoing on $F$, you wrote $E[X_{n+1} | (\frac{X_n}{2}|F)]$.  What does it mean to condition on a random variable that is being conditioned on $F$?  I think you are indeed making that up. Perhaps you meant $E[X_{n+1}|X_n, F]$ but still I don't see how or why you write that first equation, or its justification.   On the other hand, a direct use of the law of total expectation solves the problem.

Comment: I see on the next line you write $X_n|F_n$ in an equation $X_n|F_n = X_{n-1}$.  There is no such thing as a random variable conditioned on $F_n$. You are indeed making that up. For random variables $X, Y$, the conditional expectation $E[X|Y]$ is defined in probability theory, the "conditional random variable" $X|Y$ is not defined in probability theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy demonstrate that $\mathbb{E}((X_{n+1}-X_n)^2) = \mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}^2 - X_{n}^2)$ (because $X_n$ is martingale). You can see that
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}^2) &=& \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}^2|\mathcal{F}_n))\\ 
&=& \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}^2 1_{\{X_{n+1} = \frac{X_n}{2}\}}|\mathcal{F}_n)) + \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}^2 1_{\{X_{n+1} = \frac{1 + X_n}{2}\}} |\mathcal{F}_n)) \\
&=& \mathbb{E}(\frac{X_n^2}{4}\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = \frac{X_n}{2}|\mathcal{F}_n)) + \mathbb{E}((\frac{1+X_n}{2})^2\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = \frac{1+X_n}{2}|\mathcal{F}_n))\\
& =& \mathbb{E}(\frac{X_n^2}{4}(1-X_n) + (\frac{1+X_n}{2})^2X_n)\\ 
&=& \mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{4}X_n + \frac{3}{4}X_n^2)
\end{eqnarray}
then $\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}^2 - X_{n}^2) = \mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{4}X_n + \frac{3}{4}X_n^2 - X_n^2) = \frac{1}{4}\mathbb{E}(X_n(1-X_n))$

Comment: It's not immediately obvious to me how the expectation of the square of the difference of two random variables in a martingale sequence is equal to the expectation of the differences between each of their squares.

Comment: Look at this: $\mathbb{E}((X_{n+1}-X_{n})^2) = \mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}^2 + X_n^2 - 2X_n X_{n+1} ) = \mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}^2 + X_n^2 - \mathbb{E}(2X_n X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n)) = \mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}^2 + X_n^2 - 2X_{n}\mathbb{E}( X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n))=\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}^2 + X_n^2 - 2X_{n}^2) = \mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}^2 - X_{n}^2)$

Comment: Ahhh and presto! Thank you. I'm just beginning to cement my intuition with notation and I am one to shy down from algebra with ink-heavy variables.